# asking a related question to a question you asked

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question [apache 2.4 won't reload, any problem with my configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154811/apache-2-4-wont-reload-any-problem-with-my-configuration) . Now at the end of doing some more research and understanding what was wrong I ended up at a different question altogether. Is it ok to ask the related question or should I hold out for some more time hoping that somebody would answer the latter question or what should I do ?

Comment: You can ask a new question putting link to old one; also edit the old one putting a link to new.

Answer (score 11):

If you've found an answer to your original question then I'd encourage you to provide an answer to it yourself. It's perfectly acceptable to answer ones own questions, even after you've continued to research it yourself. That's fairly typical, actually.

As to your new question. If it's completely different, then I'd ask it as it's own question and not pollute the original question by asking too much. The primary intent of the Stack Exchange sites is to provide clear questions with clear answers to them, so that the original poster (OP) can get their issues resolved.

A secondary intent of the SE sites, is to provide a valuable resource to the internet so that others that come after the OP, may benefit from both the original question along with any answers that were provided.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points in @slm's answer, you should in such a case (re-)consider if your original is going to be useful for someone else.

If its usefulness is doubtful, e.g. because it the question was indirectly caused by you misreading the `man` page of a command, and being led of track by this to think a program was not working as it supposed to be.
In that case, **assuming no one answered the question yet**, you should consider deleting the original question altogether, when it has little to no value for future visitors of the site.

By creating a new U&L question with the related question, you draw more attention because it doesn't just show up on the "active" question list, but also on the "newest" question list.